# Not understand why we need to consider isomorphism from $c'$ to $\ell^{1}$ in this way.

Tags: functional-analysis

So on Wikipedia as well as many posts here on MSE. When considering the fact that $  \ell^{1} \cong c' $ we usually look at the linear map
$$y \in \ell^{1} \longmapsto \lim_{n \rightarrow \infty} x_n y_{1} + \sum_{k=1}^{\infty}x_{n}y_{n+1}$$
for some $ x=(x_1,x_2,...) \in c$ and $ y=(y_1,y_2,..) \in \ell^{1} $. But I really think this is not necessary. I think the map for the case of $c_0$
$$y \in \ell^{1} \longmapsto \sum_{k=1}^{\infty}x_{n}y_{n}$$
is really enugh. In particular to show surjectivity, write $ x= x -x_{0}+x_0 $ for some $x \in c$, then $x-x_0 \in c_{0}$, and, if we can assume that $ {c_{0}}' \cong \ell^{1}$ with the above identification, then
$$
\begin{alignat*}{2}
f(x)=f(x-x_0+x_0)&=f(x-x_0)+x_0f(e)\\
&=\sum_{k=1}^{\infty}(x_{n}-x_0)y_{n} + x_0 f(\sum_{k=1}^{\infty}e_{k})\\
&= \sum_{k=1}^{\infty}x_n y_n - \sum_{k=1}^{\infty}x_0y_{n} + \sum_{k=1}^{\infty}x_{0}f(e_k)\\
&=\sum_{k=1}^{\infty}x_{n}y_{n} - \sum_{k=1}^{\infty}x_{0}y_{n} + \sum_{k=1}^{\infty}x_0 y_{k} = \sum_{k=1}^{\infty}x_{k}y_{k}
\end{alignat*}
$$
for some functional $f \in c'$. Here we have used that one usually identify $y$ with $(f(e_{k}))_{k=1}^{\infty}$ for the case of $c_0$. Then the identification is complete. I think most of the posts I have read on MSE either neglect this issue or makes subtle mistake. But could anyone tell me where I am wrong?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that the equation $$e=\sum_{k=1}^\infty e_k$$ is not true in $c$.  The partial sums converge pointwise, but not uniformly.  Indeed, if you consider the case where $f\in c'$ is the functional that takes a sequence to its limit, then $f(e_k)=0$ for each $k$ but $f(e)=1$, so $f(e)\neq\sum f(e_k)$ and your argument fails for this $f$.

Comment: I think this solves my problem. Thanks!